# ¿Porque no funciona la función Number en script con querySelector?

Tags: javascript

La función `Number` no anda

```
var txtNum1 = document.querySelector("#idPrimero");
console.log(txtNum1)

var txtNum2 = document.querySelector("#idSegundo");
console.log(txtNum1)

var numPrimero = Number(txtNum1);
var numSegundo = Number(txtNum2);
```

Comment: ¿te sale algún  error

Comment: var varDiv = document.querySelector("#caja");
var txtNum1 = document.querySelector("#idPrimero");
console.log(txtNum1)
var txtNum2 = document.querySelector("#idSegundo");
console.log(txtNum1)

Comment: Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463659/porque-no-funciona-la-funci%c3%b3n-number-en-script-con-queryselector) tu pregunta para incluir el bloque de código que agregaste como comentario.

Comment: var txtNum1 = document.querySelector("#idPrimero");
console.log(txtNum1)

var txtNum2 = document.querySelector("#idSegundo");
console.log(txtNum1)

var numPrimero = Number(txtNum1);
var numSegundo = Number(txtNum2);

Answer (score 3):

Este NO es un error, lo que está pasando es que `querySelector` te devuelve un **nodo**, el cual no es convertible a un número

```js
console.log(Number(document.querySelector("body"))) // NaN
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Supongo que estás tratando de convertir el contenido de los elementos, o en otro caso el valor de algunos `<input>`s, así que debes usar la propiedad `innerHTML` para otros elementos que no sea un `<input>` y la propiedad `value` para un `<input>`

```
const txtNum1 = document.querySelector("#idPrimero").innerHTML;
const txtNum2 = document.querySelector("#idSegundo").innerHTML;
// Si se trata de un <input>, cambiar innerHTML por value

const numPrimero = Number(txtNum1);
const numSegundo = Number(txtNum2);

console.log(numPrimero, numSegundo);
```

Comment: Soy nueva en esto. esto es lo que quiero convertir a numero

Comment: Soy nueva en esto. Esto es lo que quiero convertir a numero.      var numPrimero = Number(txtNum1);
var numSegundo = Number(txtNum2);

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo del tipo de elemnto del cual quieras extraer el valor (el numero) podras hacerlo ya sea en unos casos con **.innerText** o en otros casos con **.value**

Asi que te recomiendo revisar eso antes. De esta manera:

```
console.log(document.querySelector("#idPrimero").value);
console.log(document.querySelector("#idPrimero").innerText);
```

Una vez sepas como has de referenciar el dato tomalo de base.

Si quieres un codigo que te valga para ambos casos puedes usar:

```
var txtNum1 = document.querySelector("#idPrimero");
var numPrimero = Number(txtNum1.value||txtNum1.innertext);
```

Pero se supone que el problema lo estas basando en algo determinado por lo que considero mas correcto una solucion adaptada al problema que intentas resolver.